# Submitted for Sweden visa to Denmark embassy want to get the passport back for emergency travel

Tags: sweden

Submitted for Sweden visa to Denmark embassy via VFS in singapore want to get the passport back for emergency travel

Answer (score 4):

> Do I have to leave my passport at the VAC?
>
> Yes. Applicant will have to leave their passport with VFS Global VAC. If for some reason the case is not processed within 6 working days and **you need your passport, kindly contact the Royal Danish Embassy directly.**

(The emphasis is mine)

[VFS](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Denmark/Singapore/english/faqs.html)